# Use code-behind variable value in serverside control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have to set some **CSS styles** for some elements on-the-fly:

```
<div runat="server" id="frmEntranceDate" 
class='<%= dateCol %> uk-float-right'>foo</div>
```

But the output html is like this:

```
<div id="frmReport_frmEntranceDate_0" class="<%= dateCol %> 
uk-float-right">foo</div>
```

How can I use `dateCol` value there? It's defined in the code behind and if I remove `runat="server"` from the ASP.net element it works, but I cannot remove it.

Comment: I believe that when doing something like this you need to replace the entire attribute with a server side value. So do the string concatenation inside the server side code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with serverside controls. You need to set its value in the code behind file.

**Markup**:

```
<div id="frmEntranceDate" runat="server">
    foo
</div>
```

**C#**:

```
frmEntranceDate.Attributes["class"] = dateCol + " uk-float-right";
```

But if you really want to use this syntax and set values inside the markup, the only approach I could think of is to bind the control.

Notice here the use of the `#` instead of the `=`.

**Markup**:

```
<div id="frmEntranceDate" runat="server" class='<%# dateCol + " uk-float-right" %>'>
    foo
</div>
```

**C#**:

```
frmEntranceDate.DataBind();
```

Comment: It does, ony if it is inside a databound control such as a GriView or a Repeater